# how to export table with first and last column excluding.?

Tags: jquery

I have many display file with many table, I want to export that file in excel, doc and png type. But in my table first column with profile_pic & last column have option or action. I dont want to export that column for each file.

My each Table with different count of column. So How to exclude that column  for each file. I got solution for one file of table But i want to multiple table.

Following code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tableExportpatient.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
```

```html
 <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Export Table Data</button>
   <ul class='id_ul'>
    <li><a href="#" onClick ="$('#datawtable').tableExport({type:'excel',escape:'false'});"> <img src='icons/xls.png' width='24px'> XLS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onClick ="$('#datawtable').tableExport({type:'doc',escape:'false'});"> <img src='icons/word.png' width='24px'> Word</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onClick ="$('#datawtable').tableExport({type:'png',escape:'false'});"> <img src='icons/png.png' width='24px'> PNG</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `ignoreColumn` option, e.g.

```
$('#datawtable').tableExport({
    type:'excel',
    escape:'false',
    ignoreColumn: [2,3] // <--- HERE
});
```

where 2,3 are the columns to exclude.

To get the index of the last column dynamically you could do smth like

```
var lastIndex = $('#datawtable').find("tr").first().find("td").last().index();
```

or even

```
var lastIndex = $('#datawtable tr:nth-child(1) td:last').index();
```

Comment: but how to use lastindex variable..?

Comment: Obviously enough it should be used in the ```ignoreColumn``` array, e.g. ```ignoreColumn[0,lastIndex]```

Comment: I had used but only ignore the first column not last column.?

Comment: how to remove first and last column from png type & doc type. Please Help me.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle demo and I'll have a look at it.